# attempted hack?

Tags: apache-2.2, hacking

I've just started seeing this appearing in our server logs...

> /P/2112/FBA73F59E6F7E78CCFF29DD8BDF46ECCAE5B73145E023BFB207C971E835645245C62CA0296DA6CDA4E62613A9C10C0DADBA941D2AD68005E57EFDC84A8ECD0ADC37C0214AD76755E48D6D1BAABF

It goes on and on for a while. In fact that's less than 10% of just one such event and there are many similar events.

I'm suspecting some attempted hack since we have no folder named "/P/" on our server.

Does anyone recognise this?

BTW, the reason I was looking at the logs at that time was that our server had just crashed, and I can't help wondering if it's related.

The server is Apache/2.0.54 (Unix) PHP/4.4.2 mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.7a JRun/4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a buffer overflow shellcode attack. I'd expect that the URL is at least 4096 chars long. The HTTP RFC does not specify a maximum URL length, although there are implicit limitations on most of the major servers, so the attacker may be attempting to cause a buffer overflow.

I'd make sure you've read the release notes for your current web server, and check that there are no outstanding security issues.

Answer (score 1):

What's the source IP?  Possible that it's some kind of DoS attack or attempt at a buffer overflow.  Can you post the entire line?

Comment: [Tue Jun 02 14:06:24 2009] [info] [client 172.16.98.242] Spelling fix: /P/448/FBA73F59E6F7E78CCFF29DD8BDF46ECCE0B5E872557872C99849F03E5825BD858ECB22A02F3F899EBDA8CC1D67AC24D8CE9E9670742817BD30834A95C3DCD5CCCA40C2CEFAD205FDC647FDBB647E954C0DF5A5817DFF928C830714F8849D409110BB65E7D1C007F5D139E843C3679DD9C28DFAA794ABF1CC232E7224A2ACCBBC1A3A3F8A4670EABFF98D5A0CB61914ADC1A1799661C8EB872ADB926572176698F360A219026C8E10180333B9823A2DCB74C9FB8B276B668A57C95C28D9AE3D2FA93A872F706A839836CBAC09E920420002F95CE948C1E8D0EC6092435FC9A24D: 2 candidates
(We are using mod_spelling)

Comment: There are dozens of these requests from the same machine

Comment: It's a private network (172.16.*.*), do you use these in your company? Otherwise it might be somehow spoofed...

Comment: Yeah, it's an internal address, so I assume we have an infected machine on the inside of the network.

Comment: Go to it and plug it off the network physically. Don't turn it off, you might want to check how it was hacked first.

Comment: Well, if he is not experience with forensics (and has no one to help), don't try to act smart to find how the attacker got it. You can make things worse. Just unplug, shutdown and reinstall it completely. From now on, use an IDS (HIDS or NIDS) to actively monitor your network to see if you can see what is going on.